# What is the difference between exit(0) & exit(1) used in PERL?

Tags: perl

So, I came across a **PERL** script while working on an already implemented project. Since its confidential, I cannot reveal much details but the code is somewhat like this :

```
if(defined($x)){
    exit(0);
}
#...........
#.some other code.
#...........

if(!defined($y)){
      print "ERROR !";
      exit(1);
}
```

I am assuming exit(1) is in error conditions and exit(0) is for success cases. But since we are already printing the error message, what is the difference here between **exit(0)** and **exit(1)?**

Comment: This is not limited to Perl. [Exit codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) are a general concept to have a program signal whether it could do what it was asked or whether something went wrong, so that other programs (usually the calling program) can react to it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, PERL and linux work the same way , is that what it is?

Comment: The name of the language is Perl, not PERL; it's not an acronym.

Comment: @AshleshaSunilAgate, `exit` in perl is the same as exiting in C or any other language, so yes, normal operating system conventions apply as to the meaning of that exit status and how other programs are going to interpret it.

Comment: @AshleshaSunilAgate, ...whereas `exit 0` is how one writes "exit with a status of success" in shell, and `exit(0)` is how one writes it in perl, the meaning is the same both ways.

Answer (score 6):

The process that spawned the program can check what number you returned. `0` typically means "no error" (and it's the default exit status for Perl scripts). Other values are program specific.

For example, `grep` exits with

- `0`, when it found a match
- `1`, when it found no matches
- `2`, when an error occurred

so you can do

```sh
if grep -q foo file; then
   echo 'match'
else
   echo 'no match (or error)'
fi
```

---

You probably should have used `die` instead of `print` and `exit`. `die("$msg\n")` outside of an `eval` is roughly equivalent to

```perl
print STDERR "$msg\n";
exit( $! || ( $? >> 8 ) || 255 );
```

So it's simpler, the message is printed to STDERR (not STDOUT) as it should, and it's guaranteed to exit with a non-zero code (and hopefully one that is meaningful when debugging).

Comment: Can you explain the difference in what is printed or happens internally in my case ?

Comment: What do you mean by "your case", and difference between your case and what?

Comment: @AshleshaSunilAgate: From the perspective of your code, there is no difference. But something is calling your program (whether that's another program or the user, via a command shell). If whatever is calling your program checks the return value, then it will get 0 in the first case and 1 in the second. It is a Unix tradition that 0 means the program ran successfully and any non-zero return values indicate errors. The meaning of specific non-zero return values is specific to the program in question.